# iOS7 Core Data NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, exc-bad-access

I'm developing an iPhone application for a year and haven't such issue before iOS7 release. I'm using Core Data in my app. All operations like inserting or fetching data are being completed as it is supposed to be, but `deleteObject` method doesn't work properly. Here's my code.

```
-(void)clearLocalSessionListUpdates {
    User* user = [self currentUser];
    // only delete LSU object (cascade delete rule)
    LocalSessionUpdate* lsu = user.localSessionUpdates;
    if (lsu != nil){
        [context deleteObject:lsu];
    }
    [lsu removeDeletedSessions:lsu.deletedSessions];
    [lsu removeNewSessions:lsu.newSessions];
    SessionUpdate* su = lsu.updatedSessions;
    [su removeRate:su.rate];
    [su removeEvaluation:su.evaluation];
    su.timestamp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    [self save];
}
```

On the `[context deleteObject:lsu]` line app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. It started to appear only in the iOS7 SDK (since beta) and I don't know how to figure it out. In addition I will say that my app is "thread safe" in this place. All operations with Core Data are being forced in the main thread. All delete rules are set to `Nullify`.

Comment: Could you post a full error message?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko Full error message is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1b)`. That's all. I don't think it will help you.

Comment: Are you using multiple NSManagedObjectContext instances.

Comment: @insane-36 No. I'm using only one NSManagedObjectContext instance and I'm forcing all the operations in the main thread.

Comment: So these operations are done in main thread, are you certain that managedObjectContext is also created in main thread.

Comment: @insane-36 Yes. I've double-checked it. As I mentioned, it was working in the iOS6 and now it doesn't.